# UIViewcontrollers inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating an app in objective C programmatically. I have an UICollectionView with Some pie chart, bar graph, table views and some views. So what I did is create separate viewcontrollers with pie chart, bar graph and tableviews with model data. when loading the collectionview cell I take screenshot of the Viewcontroller corresponding to the cell and save it in cache. basically when the cell loads for the first time the viewcontroller is initialized, taken screen shot and saved in cache. The problem I am facing is a choppy scroll when scrolling for the first time since the viewcontroller is initialized and taken screenshot but later it becomes smooth as it takes the image from cache. when the user refreshes I clear the cache and repeat the process again(The main reason for choppy scroll is the main thread being interrupted by initializing the ViewController) any better idea to solve my problem? Below is the code while Taking screenShot

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:snapURLPortrait.path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error1];

   //Directory Created Successfully.

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
  [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

Imageview is an UIView and imageSize is size that I want to take Image as screenshot

Note: I tried using the UIViewControllers inside UICollectioViewCell instead of screen shots I am getting choppy scroll all the time atleast in my way I get choppy scroll only at first.

Comment: put some code for better understand.

Comment: @yagneshdobariya I posted a scenario and I need a better solution for that I don't have any problem with code. The reason for choppy scroll is due to main thread being interrupted.